# Model specification for a tricky (for me) situation: Not quite factorial

Tags: r, linear-model, experiment-design, contrasts

i'm getting myself confused trying to organize my model.

the data comes from a study of tinned food products.  a whole stack of tins are drained, then contents from all tins are pooled and mixed, so we have a bucket of this product.

this is then divided into five portions.

- one: the drained product
- two: the drained product rinsed at 20 degree C under solution A
- three: the drained product rinsed at 20 degree C under solution B
- four: the drained product rinsed at 40 degree C under solution A
- five: the drained product rinsed at 40 degree C under solution B

nutritional things are measured (destructively) on each of the five portions (three times for each of the five portions).

i'm not sure how to structure the model.  we end up with table of means like this for example

`| Drained | 20 deg | 40 deg 
--------+---------+--------+--------
Drained | 20      |        | 
Sol A   |         | 17     | 12 
Sol B   |         | 13     | 10`

i hope that is clear.

so its not a factorial design because (eg) the drained product isnt measured only at 20deg, but at 20deg in sol A or 20deg in sol B.

or do i really just have one variable with five levels (drained; 20A, 20B, 40A, 40B)?

i want to test planned hypotheses like the differences between sol A and sol B, and 20 vs 40 deg, the difference between original (drained) and 20deg rinsing with sol A, and a few others (including the interaction between temp and solution).

how can I  set up this properly for testing hypothesis in r?  i imagined using lm or similar, but I'm not sure how to set things up.

thanks for any help.

wiggin

Comment: "i want to test planned hypotheses like the differences between sol A and sol B, and 20 vs 40 deg" You don't need the "Drained" treatment for that.

Comment: true. but i also want to test again the drained. (should have said).  so for example, does rinsing at 20 deg reduce any nutritional things.  i;ll fix question. thanls roland.

Comment: Well, you can use two models: without the drained treatment `aov(lm(y ~ sol * temp, data = ...))` and with the drained treatment `aov(lm(y ~ f, data = ...))` plus pairwise comparisons, where `f` denotes each of your five treatments

Comment: thanks. wasn't thinking of using two models, i just considered one. thanks roland.